# Throwing water into lava

Tags: thermodynamics, water, boiling-point

While discussing magma in class with my students, I showed [a video](https://youtu.be/AuWgTwlfSlA?t=93) of a man throwing water onto molten, running lava.  A large flame ensued.  I realize that the water is being converted into steam and expanding extremely rapidly, but why does this create a small "explosion," if you will?

Surely none of the lava is being "atomized" into the air in small droplets, is it?  But even so, they would not light aflame.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0XgpYXVN-Kk

Comment: Are you certain it was a _flame_ and not just lava bubbles with thin enough walls that it appeared more orange than red, thus giving the _illusion_ of a flame?

Comment: I think linking the video you are referring to would be potentially helpful in answering this question.

Comment: The first thing I think of, [is this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_splitting#Thermal_decomposition_of_water).

Comment: Edited the original to add the hyperlink on the words "a video".  Should be about 1 minute 30 secs into the video.  The thermal decomposition sounds like a plausible explanation, but basaltic magma sits around 1250C at best.  Surely not hot enough to decompose a sufficient enough amount of water?  Or perhaps the initial decomposition and ignition creates more heat, starting a chain reaction?

Comment: The liquid looks like it is in a water bottle, but is it water? From that amount of liquid and flame I'd suspect alcohol or gasoline. The numb-numb was putting on a show not a science demonstration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Steam explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_explosion) generally the flame [is due to the hydrogen](https://hvo.wr.usgs.gov/volcanowatch/archive/2000/00_03_09.html) produced when water is superheated so thermal decomposed into $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{O2}$.

Quoting wikipedia:

> Steam explosions are not normally chemical explosions, although a
>   number of substances react chemically with steam (for example,
>   zirconium and superheated graphite react with steam and air
>   respectively to give off hydrogen, which burns violently in air) so
>   that chemical explosions and fires may follow.

Comment: Theory:  Is the lava hot enough to decompose some of the water into hydrogen and oxygen gas, thus making way for a hydrogen explosion, which releases a lot of energy, which is absorbed by other waters, which decomposes more of them?  It seems like good potential for a chain reaction.